# Why doesn't passing that.method as a parameter work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

In a class that represent a request, I try to process it with Q promises and after that, have two simple handlers to send the result of the processing. Why doesn't this work:

```
Request.prototype.process = function() {
    var that = this;
    return that.getParameter('method')
    .then(function(method) {
        // ... Some processing
    })
    .then(that.replyOK)
    .fail(that.replyError);
};
```

But this does:

```
Request.prototype.process = function() {
    var that = this;
    return that.getParameter('method')
    .then(function(method) {
        // ... Some processing
    })
    .then(function(error) {
        that.replyOK(error);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        that.replyError(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Probably because your `replyOK` and `replyError` functions care about what `this` is inside of their bodies, which is not bound as you think it is in your usage in the first case, while it is in the second.

Comment: Are you sure the semicolon after `.then(...)` and before `.fail(...)` is there in the second example?

Comment: As Barray said, in the first case, *this* within *replyOK* and *replyError* is not set in the call so it will default to the global object (or remain undefined in strict mode), but is set to *that* in the second case.

Comment: If `that.replyOK` worked, then you wouldn't need the `that` variable at all.

Comment: What others have said about scope and `this` is correct but the fact that the two sample blocks of code behave differently reveals that either `replyOK` and `replyError` are conceptually flawed or your `Request` instance was created without the all-important `new`. Within every method, you should write the code with the expectation that `this` reliably refers back to the instance of `Request`, which will only happen when instances are created with `new Request()`. However, [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/#postcomment) tells you how to be lazy with `new`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I'm new to JS, but it already seems to me like everyone has their own idea of how to 'properly' do OOP there. So, saying that using 'new' is undoubtedly, universally a bad practice, may be a stretch... But the article you linked to is very interesting nonetheless, thanks.

Comment: Golergka, yes it's certainly true that everyone has his own ideas. Toleranace to the absence of `new` is really something that lib' writers should consider (the author of the article, John Resig, is the creator of jQuery). In your own code, when calling your own *ad hoc* Constructors, you are far less likely than a lib' consumer to forget a `new`, but Resig's approach is certainly something to keep in your tool-chest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is mostly lexically scoped. This means that in:

```
 function foo(){
     var that = this;
     //...
 }
```

The variables accessing that in the following lines of foo `that` is set to what you expect it to. If you pass functions with locals defines elsewhere, `that` won't be captured in their lexical (variable) environment.

JavaScript also has dynamic `this` , a method's `this` is determined by the currently calling object. For example:

```
var a = {
           x:3,
           getX:function(){ return this.x; }
        };
var b = {x:5};
b.getX = a.getX;
b.getX(); // returns 5
a.getX(); // returns 3
a.getX.call(b); // set `this` explicitly with .call, returns 5
var x = a.getX;
x(); // global x or undefined.
```

It's possible to fixate `this` using `Function.prototype.bind` as such:

```
Request.prototype.process = function() {
    return this.getParameter('method')
    .then(function(method) {
        // ... Some processing
    })
    .then(this.replyOK.bind(this))
    .fail(this.replyError.bind(this));
};
```

Or, in EcmaScript 6 syntax (not available in node yet, but soon):

```
Request.prototype.process = () => { // arrow functions have lexical `this` 
    return that.getParameter('method')
    .then(function(method) {
        // ... Some processing
    })
    .then(this.replyOK)
    .fail(this.replyError);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I didn't quite understand this sentence: "If you pass functions with locals defines elsewhere, that won't be captured in their lexical (variable) environment." Are you sure that you're talking about "that" and not "this"? Because if "that" wouldn't be captured, none of this would work at all.

Comment: @golergka only the _closure_ is captured. For example `function a(){ alert(that.foo); }; function b(){ this.foo = "Bar"; var that = this; a();}` would _not_ work in JavaScript, but would work in languages with dynamic scoping (like Perl). See http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/20/what-is-lexical-scoping/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Eric's blog! As someone who's coming from C#, I found it to be most usable :)

Comment: @golergka I saw, that's why I recommended that article :) It's also a great read. Glad I could help.

Comment: Yeah, since replyOK is defined elsewhere. replyOk and replyError have to be themselves created with `=>`